# Spring data redis - How to use hashOperation's scan method to get keys or values based on pattern?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I have never worked on Redis and Spring boot. I want to use Redis as a cache.

I have been using `hashOperations` for get/set operations. I have configured the `RedisTemplate` to stop weird hashes from getting prepended to a key.

I have a class called `Post` which I am caching. A user can create multiple posts. The key gets generated like this : `userId::postId` and the post data gets cached.

How to use `scan` method of RedisTemplate to get all posts of a particular user? I tried `ScanOptions` and the pattern `*` but I am certainly doing something wrong as I am not getting any data. There aren't many links or youtube videos on `scan` and `ScanOptions` so I am finding it difficult to implement.

This is what I have wrote for getting all posts of a user:

```java
public List<Post> getPostsByUid(String uid) {
    String key = uid + "::";
    ScanOptions scanOptions = ScanOptions.scanOptions().match("*").count(20).build();
    Cursor cursor = hashOperations.scan(key, scanOptions);
    List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        posts.add((Post)cursor.next());
    }
    return posts;
}
```

This is the `savePost` method

```java
public Post savePost(Post post) {
    String key = post.getUid() + "::" + post.getPostid();
    hashOperations.put(key, "", post);
    return post;
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hashOperations.scan` scans within a hash. But you want to scan within whole database (Redis).

```java
String keyPattern = uid + "::" + "*";
ScanOptions scanOptions = ScanOptions.scanOptions().match(keyPattern).count(20).build();
Cursor c = redisConnection.scan(options); // scanning in db
while (c.hasNext()) {
    // c.next() is Redis key. Use this in hashOperations to get your Post.
}
```

Comment: Can we use hashOperations when Redis is used as a cache or is it only used when Redis is used as a database?

Comment: Always. hashOperations just means the operations will be done on Redis hash data structure.

Comment: how can i inject redisConnection? thanks